# Enforcing Maximum Login Attempts in ASP.NET MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, security

I want to implement a maximum login attempt amount when my users login in order to prevent against automated brute force attacks on logins.

I can think of a few different options of how I could do this, but all of them seem to leave large security holes.

What methods/options do I have for doing this? I obviously cant use a hidden field, and I cant use a session because there is none. What is the protocol, or the best practice method for doing this.

I am looking at 10 attempts before I enforce a password reset, or temporary deactivation of the account.

**NOTE - I am looking at what methods I have for storing the login amount, how I am differentiating login attempts,etc**

Comment: *I am looking at what methods I have for storing the login amount* -- Store it in a field in the user's account record in the database on the server.  *how I am differentiating login attempts* -- Increment the aforementioned field, lock the account if the count gets too high.  If you're simply trying to prevent automated attacks, use a captcha.

Comment: No you are not missing anything, it is a basic question. I am aware of how to increment, but I didn't really consider it as a field on the user account. Are there any drawbacks to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent the user from trying multiple logins and passwords you would need to track the ip along with the number of failed login attempts.  The ips would be stored in a different table then the authenticated user.

If the same user ip has 10 invalid logins then no login they enter will work even if they change the username and password combo.

Of course they could change there ip at any time but if you don't show them that they have been tracked and keep the form as normal and result the same they will keep trying but not actually validating anything.  Everything will just return a invalid credentials like a normal user would see.  If you want them to stop hammering your server you could setup IIS to block them also but this will lead them to just switch ips.  Eventually there list will run out and they will go elsewhere.

you could also email the user after 3 attempts notifying them an invalid login has taken place and if this is not them tell them to perform some action.  I know sites like LogMeIn do this.

Comment: One could have multiple users coming from the same IP address, so I'm not sure this would be the best strategy.

Answer (score 1):

I think the generic pattern is that failed login attempts are tracked on the server, not the client, and that when the server has logged X number of failures for a particular account that account is locked. The user then needs to reset their account through a previously validated contact mechanism (email, phone number, challenge question, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I edited my question to be a little more specific for what I am looking for.

Comment: This is going to be particular to your implementation. In whatever manner you're representing your user collection (database, map, etc.) you'll want to increment an unsuccessful login counter and when it gets to X you would set a flag on your user record. You can check out http://forums.asp.net/t/918243.aspx for a brief discussion but I wouldn't use view state for this. Are you interested in something like this? http://www.asp.net/security/tutorials/validating-user-credentials-against-the-membership-user-store-cs